# Magento URL Rewrites not working after 1.3->1.4 Upgrade

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.4

I have mostly upgraded Magento 1.3 to 1.4 but I cannot get the Product or Category Pages Showing properly.

Note I have removed a SEO Suite ( Mageworx - horrible experience ) and removed the relevant attributes from the database.

I have also tried everything here https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/664-fixing-url-rewrites-with-magento

Still I get the standard 404 Page when I go to any page or category ( including emptying the core rewrite table and reindexing ) .

I Can go directly to the category page fine ( e.g. www.mysite.net/catalog/category/view/id/115/ )

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I removed Mageworx Attributes from the database and a couple of other php issues and working now.